# kill -s SIGTERM kills parent process and one level child process only

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

I've been doing some experimenting with writing a command to kill parent and all it's children recursively. I've a script as below

parent.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/oracle/child.sh &
sleep infinity
```

child.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep infinity
```

Started command using

```
su oracle -c parent.sh &
```

I see a process tree like below

```
[root@source ~]# ps -ef | grep "/home/oracle"
root     14129  1171  0 12:39 pts/1    00:00:00 su oracle -c /home/oracle/parent.sh
oracle   14130 14129  0 12:39 ?        00:00:00 /bin/bash /home/oracle/parent.sh
oracle   14131 14130  0 12:39 ?        00:00:00 /bin/bash /home/oracle/child.sh
```

When I send sigterm to 14129 using `kill -s SIGTERM 14129` it appears to kill 14129 and then 14130 goes down as well immediately; but 14131 stays up for a very long time. The last level child appears to have been reparented and has become a zombie.

```
oracle   14131     1  0 12:39 ?        00:00:00 /bin/bash /home/oracle/child.sh
```

1. If kill doesn't terminate any child processes why did 14130 get killed when I sent a SIGTERM to 14129?
2. If kill can kill child processes, why would does it go only one level down? Is the behavior here guaranteed?

Comment: This is documented behavior for [`su` signal handling](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/su.1.html#SIGNALS).

Comment: Suggesting to investigate `pkill --parent PID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant part of what pilcrow **[provided](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/su.1.html#SIGNALS)** is this:

> SIGNALS         top
>
> ```
>    Upon receiving either SIGINT, SIGQUIT or SIGTERM, su terminates
>    its child and afterwards terminates itself with the received
>    signal. 
>
>    >> The child is terminated by SIGTERM, 
>    >> (then) after unsuccessful attempt (to kill with SIGTERM) and 
>    >> (after) 2 seconds of delay (,) the child is (then) killed 
>    >> by SIGKILL [a second, harsher method].
> ```

That harsher method, SIGKILL, **prevents** that child process from attempting to kill its own children, hence the zombie state.

I haven't used it myself, but it seems that something like

```
killall --process-group parent.sh
```

would kill all processes tied to the process group associated with the "**parent.sh**" script.  **BUT** ... not sure if "**--wait**" will serve you well, if the method used in the attempt to terminate is not being accepted.

Comment: I don't think SIGKILL is relevant. What matters is that Bash doesn't kill its children when it's killed. That's the default behavior for all processes: processes don't kill their children when they die unless they go out of their way to do so like su does.

Comment: SIGKILL would prevent the script's ... trap ... command from taking effect.  From my understanding, SIGTERM would allow the traps to take action (i.e. execute any kill children routine defined).  Admittedly no trap in the example provided.